# Saving a composite datawindow in PowerBuilder

Tags: save, format, powerbuilder, composite, datawindow

Is there a way to save results in a composite datawindow as a text or excel spreadsheet? Powerbuilder states for composites the format to save it is PSReport. That doesn't work for what I'm trying to do. Is there any other workaround for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

A composite datawindow may contain any number of nested datawindows. So if memory serves, you cannot save the entire composite datawindow as data in a meaningful way (SaveAs will just give you a one-line bit of meaningless data), but you CAN save each of the nested datawindows inside the composite.

Here is some PFC code I wrote (for inside a menu item) which makes a copy of a nested report and then executes a SaveAs (dialog in this case):

```
            //must create a 'dummy' datawindow,
            //and put the data on the nested report into it

            u_dw ldw_Temp
            Window lw_Parent
            String ls_Syntax, ls_Error

            If Not IsValid(i_dwo) Then
                    MessageBox('Unexpected Error', &
                                              'The pointer to the datawindow object was invalid. Contact Systems.')
                    Return
            End If

            If i_dwo.Type = 'report' Then
                    //continue
            Else
                    MessageBox('Unexpected Error', &
                                              'The pointer did not refer to a report. Contact Systems.')
                    Return
            End If

            If idw_Parent.of_GetParentWindow(lw_Parent) = 1 Then
                    ls_Syntax = i_dwo.object.datawindow.syntax
                    If lw_Parent.OpenUserObject(ldw_Temp) = 1 Then
                            If ldw_Temp.Create(ls_Syntax,ls_Error) = 1 Then
                                    ldw_Temp.Object.Data.Primary = i_dwo.Object.Data.Primary
                                    ldw_Temp.Event pfc_SaveAs()
                            Else
                                    If IsNull(ls_Error) Or ls_Error = '' Then ls_Error = '<unknown error>'
                                    MessageBox('Error','Error creating datawindow object: ' + ls_Error)
                            End If
                            lw_Parent.CloseUserObject(ldw_Temp)
                    Else
                            MessageBox('Error','Error creating datawindow control on ' + lw_Parent.ClassName())
                    End If
            Else
                    MessageBox('Error','Unable to obtain pointer to the parent window.')
            End If
```

Basically this code gets the syntax of the datawindow object underlying the nested report (`ls_Syntax = i_dwo.object.datawindow.syntax` above), then creates a datawindow control on the parent form and loads that syntax into it, and then copies the data from the one into the other. Finally it calls SaveAs on the copy, and the user is presented with a dialog asking where they want to save the data from the nested report and in what format.

You could automate this so that it saves each nested report as a separate file, and then if you like you could automate the formation of those separate files into a single file (sheets inside a workbook, appended text files, etc).

There are other ways to do what you are asking, depending on what exactly you are trying to accomplish.

The `i_dwo` variable was loaded in the right-mouse up even of the datawindow control (the dwo event variable there).

That may get you running, please ask questions if you have any.